# Declare global variable and passing value across methods in Python OOP

Tags: python, oop

Declare global variable and passing value across methods
in Python OOP.

So, I would like to pass the result of nethod1 to 
method2.

For example

```
import pandas as pd

class ExampleClass(object):

 def method1(self):
  file_path="/some/path/"
  file_data="populaion_data.csv"

  data=pd.read_csv(file_path+file_data)
  res = data.head(5)  


 def method2(self):
  """
  In his method, i would like to do the following tasks
  (1)read the "res" from the method1.
  (2)want to get the value of "file_path" from method1 again. 
  """
```

And, also I think it would be better to declare the
"file_path" value as a global vaiable, so I can use that 
value across several methods.

Comment: No, the whole *point* of classes is to avoid global state. Use *instance variables*.

Comment: Also, just in case you are running python3.x, there is no need for `class ExampleClass(object):`. Just use `class ExampleClass:`

Comment: @juanpa.arrivillaga yes you are right. got the solution. thank you

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you want the variable to be accessible across methods in the same class, you can just declare an instance variable:

```
    import pandas as pd

    class ExampleClass(object):
        def __init__(self):
            self.file_path = "/some/path/" 
            self.res = ''

        def method1(self):
            file_data="populaion_data.csv"
            data=pd.read_csv(self.file_path+file_data)
            self.res = data.head(5)  


        def method2(self):
            """
            In his method, i would like to do the following tasks
            (1)read the "res" from the method1.
            (2)want to get the value of "file_path" from method1 again. 
            """
            #self.file_path and self.res will be accessible here too.
            print (self.file_path, self.res)

    a = ExampleClass()
    a.method2()
```

Comment: I didnt realise init was missing. Added it to the code. Thanks!

Comment: @ChaitanyaBangera I think this is the answer I was looking for. Thanks very much for your time and effort.

Answer (score 0):

You can do the following:

```
def method1(self):
    self.file_path = "some/path/"
    file_data = "population_data.csv"
    data=pd.read_csv(file_path+file_data)
    self.res = data.head(5)  

def method2(self):
    print(self.file_path, self.res)
```

Note that you will have to call method2 after method1 however. You can also call `method1` from `method2` and then use the values like this:

```
def method1(self):
    file_path = "some/path/"
    file_data = "population_data.csv"
    data=pd.read_csv(file_path+file_data)
    res = data.head(5)  
    return (file_path, res)

def method2(self):
    file_path, res = self.method1()
```

You can also define it as a class variable or a static variable. 
To define it as a static variable simply do:

```
class ExampleClass:
    file_path = "some/path"
    data=pd.read_csv(file_path+file_data)
    res = data.head(5)

    def method2(self):
        print(self.file_path, self.res)
```

Comment: your code example was helpful for me for the next steps. your answer was one step further than my original question. thank you very much.

Answer (score 0):

This is not an OOP question. With OOP you manipulate *objects* defined by *Classes* which are, from a basic point of view, *types* A *type* is a component having a *state* (data) and behavior (integrated functions called methods). Thus, there is no *global variables* in OOP. Data can be provided to objects trough methods parameters and the result of the processing should be returned by the method.

In this cas, I don't see the reason why those functions are within a class except if you need objects as defined in previous answers. Based on your code example, this is resolved with functions for which, data should be passed as parameters:

```
import pandas as pd
DEFAULT_FILE_PATH ="/some/path/"

def method1(filename, file_path='/'):
    data=pd.read_csv(file_path + file_data)
    return data.head(5)  


def method2(data, file_path='/'):
"""
In his method, i would like to do the following tasks
(1)read the "res" from the method1.
(2)want to get the value of "file_path" from method1 again. 
"""
```

So you know what `file_path` is, you can use it as

```
method2(method1("populaion_data.csv", DEFAULT_FILE_PATH), DEFAULT_FILE_PATH)
```

Comment: your suggestion helps, however, this is just the beginning of a possible long program, and I am sure I am going to use some class inheritance later on, so wanted to keep all the functions/methods within a class so that I can use them later. appreciate your time.